# "Missing ; before statement" script error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using code to make gForms add dates to gCal using info on this page:
http://www.considerednormal.com/2014/04/adding-a-google-calendar-event-using-google-forms/

I get red error; see this pic: 
[image: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s28/sh/cedddc13-74e5-4b5e-a8ef-4ddb249a8211/6764984863fa74355e60059afae40dd8]

Your advice greatly appreciated. (Note, I'm not a coder.)
Thx, Vic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would probably help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

just put "" after = and before ;

Comment: This would be a better answer with some explanation, ergo: Javascript, the basis of Google Apps Script, has 4 basic [data types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp), which can be combined to create more complex types. (There's also [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), which are actually objects but appear string-like in code.) In your case, you are assigning a *string* value to the variable `calendarId`, so the string should be contained within single or double quotes.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because although it is intrinsically correct it does not deserve a +1.  The comment above (Mogsdad) would !!! ;-)

Comment: Hey wijaya - these comments are hints! Update your answer with the additional information, and THEN it will be a good answer, and deserve up-votes.